# Meteor: how to remove HTML comments from production code?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I've noticed that my `<!-- HTML comments -->` have made their way into my production minified JS code.

How do I get rid of them?

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a request to the meteor team to make this change. It's currently not possible